# Eclipse + Git - How to show only modified files in compare with option?

Tags: eclipse, git, compare

I'm trying to compare my project with a previous commit on git. Eclipse shows in the Git Tree Compare window every single file of the project, is there a way to show just the modified files?

I'm using Eclipse Juno + EGit 2.0

Comment: Maybe it thinks those files have changed because of EOL characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select two commits in the history view and use the context menu "Compare with each other", then you get a diff with only modified files. For your use case, one of the two commits must be the uppermost.

However, this includes all projects in the workspace, so it might give you some noise, if you had changes between the 2 commits in other projects than the one to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Try the (Right click) Team-> Synchronize Workspace. You need to select a project for this menu item to show up.  This should open the Synchronize Perspective. There are some 'modes' you can choose like only show incoming, or outgoing, etc...

I find this view a bit better than the 'compare with'. Not sure why EGit has both.

Comment: I don't know why, but the synchronize option give me the same result as the compare with =/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but nothing has changed.  egit doesnt do the job for multi-project development, in terms of presenting a focused delta between file hierarchies, branches, commits, change sets, what have you.  I use beyond compare software, which is low-cost, but not free, to get the required view (provided at job-site).  If anyone knows of an o/s tool or eclipse plug-in which handles this task well, please chime in.